# Does the image in this scene look out of place? I can't seem to incorporate it into the scene

Tags: images, mobile

So, in this scene I have cards which can come with our without an image, and for those who do come with an image I can't seem to incorporate into the scene cohesively. It's hard to me to explain how but it looks off.

[image]

Buttons on the bottom aren't finished, I am going to put some arrow icons in them.

All kinds of critiques are appreciated!

Thanks

edit, new picture:

[image]

edit 2:

[image]

edit 3:

[image]

edit 4:
image 1:

[image]

image 2:

[image]

Comment: Just offhand.. the width of the photo should the the same as the width of the banner above it.

Comment: @Scott okay, makes sense. I edited my post, what do you think of the newer version?

Comment: Thank you for this new preview. To me it looks better than your first draft. I hope you like it. Hopefully it will inspire other members to also propose improvements.

Comment: At the moment the pages are still rather "top heavy" as you are still working on those buttons. Right? Feels like you have to put some real bold colours into those navigation buttons (not white) to balance the box with the infos and the photo on the top.

Comment: @MartinZaske Your comment on my pages being "top heavy" really made me think, and made me come up with a new design. What do you think?

Comment: Better than before. Seems you are selling cars or parts, not their information. So putting the main item first feels logical to me. Having the very intence colour-block nearer the center will take the eyes from the photo to the information and then to the "user response". Hope you get a few more opinions.

Comment: @MartinZaske what do you think now? Thanks!!

Comment: @Levon Yes, on edit 4 you have made good improvements on the navigation and details on the page bottoms. Personally, I had liked the photo-on-the-very-top from your edit 3. But where is everybody else? Seems they like to answer specific technical questions rather than giving styling-advice on real projects. I hope you know your target audience and I hope those are also grumpy old overworked jacks of many trades who enjoy their smartphones for a few minutes each day. Otherwise you should maybe not even listen to me...   ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show us one version where the photo is right on the colored info-box (no gap) and without rounded corners. Bring the sidebars as far down as the bottom edge of the photo. Then we shall have another look.

And no white bath tub under the photo please, hope this is only a hiccup from my browser.

Comment: The sidebars denote another card to the left and right, so bringing the sidebars down isn't what I'm looking for. Mostly because if the image has the same width as the card it should show to the left and right as well, do you understand? Anyway, I've updated the post with what you asked for. Thanks